# Gradle build getting failed when adding uber dependency

Tags: android

I am integrating uber in my app. When I am adding the dependency provided by uber

```
compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
```

build is getting failed with below mentioned error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.
```

Please help

Comment: And what are the details in the console?

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: it might be problem with your internet connection as it compiles fine in my project.

Comment: @VivekMishra : Issue is not with the internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same problem. (And just to mention the dependency version is updated to 0.5.4, it doesn't matter much)

Paste this code in your `build.gradle` file

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}
```

It must work